# Java String.replaceAll() replace across newlines

Tags: java, regex

Consider following code.

```
String s = "000000Xabcdefgh\nijkX00000000";
s = s.replaceAll("X.*X", "");
System.out.println(s);
```

I expect `Xabcdefgh\nijkX` to get replaced with an empty string, but since there is a newline in the middle, nothing gets replaced. Why is the regex matching terminated at newline? How can I ignore newlines when matching regex?

Comment: s= s.replaceAll("X([^X]*)X", "");  It replaces everything between two X's.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String s = "000000Xabcdefgh\nijkX00000000";
s = s.replaceAll("X.*( |\t|\r\n|\r|\n).*X", "");
System.out.println(s);
```

This will take care of all other white-space/newline chars.